# How to make sure that the boids avoid walls 100% of the time

Tags: c++, math, collision-detection

I am trying to make boids simulation. Currently, I have a world where they can roam around and have to avoid Obstacles. My obstacles are defined as lines and I am using line intersection to see if there are any walls in front of it and if there are, I steer away from it. In fact, there are two lines at `direction angle + FOV` and `direction angle - FOV`. If either of these lines are colliding, the boid will turn away. The condition for turning that I set is to keep steering as long as the average of the dot product of those tow lines is less than the `cos` of the `direction angle`. Here is the code.

```
for (auto& boid : boids)
        {
            //finding the tow vectors to + and - fov from the direction angle
            olc::vf2d lessFov = { (-std::cos(boid.DirectionAngle() - boid.collisionFov) * boid.collisionSensoryRange) + boid.position.x,
                (-std::sin(boid.DirectionAngle() - boid.collisionFov) * boid.collisionSensoryRange) + boid.position.y};

            olc::vf2d plusFov = { (-std::cos(boid.DirectionAngle() + boid.collisionFov) * boid.collisionSensoryRange) + boid.position.x,
                (-std::sin(boid.DirectionAngle() + boid.collisionFov) * boid.collisionSensoryRange) + boid.position.y };

            for (auto& obs : map.obstacles)
            {
                olc::vf2d intersectionPoint1{};
                olc::vf2d intersectionPoint2{};

                if (checkLineIntersect(lessFov, boid.position, obs.p1, obs.p2, intersectionPoint1) ||
                    checkLineIntersect(plusFov, boid.position, obs.p1, obs.p2, intersectionPoint2))
                {

                    //This is the problem
                    if (boid.position.dot( (intersectionPoint1 + intersectionPoint2) / 2 ) < std::cos(boid.DirectionAngle()))
                        boid.rotationAngle -= elapsedTime * obstacleAvoidancePriority;
                    else
                        boid.rotationAngle += elapsedTime * obstacleAvoidancePriority;
                }
            }

        }
```

I am almost pleased with the result that it gives me except for the fact that occasionally, some of the boids manage to go through the walls(its rare but happens), such as the one trapped inside the box in the picture below. It was spawned outside but managed to get in.

[image]

I want a way that ensures that the boids can never go through walls. Thanks.

Edit:

I just noticed that in this part of code, `else` clause is never executed. The condition was just something I dreamt up with a limited understanding of dot product because I wanted them to not always turn in the same direction.

```
//This is the problem
if (boid.position.dot( (intersectionPoint1 + intersectionPoint2) / 2 ) < std::cos(boid.DirectionAngle()))
    boid.rotationAngle -= elapsedTime * obstacleAvoidancePriority;
else
    boid.rotationAngle += elapsedTime * obstacleAvoidancePriority;
```

Here is another way i experimented with.

```
bool i1 = checkLineIntersect(lessFov, boid.position, obs.p1, obs.p2, intersectionPoint1);
bool i2 = checkLineIntersect(plusFov, boid.position, obs.p1, obs.p2, intersectionPoint2);

if (i1 && !i2)
    boid.rotationAngle += elapsedTime * obstacleAvoidancePriority;
else if(i2 && !i1)
    boid.rotationAngle -= elapsedTime * obstacleAvoidancePriority;
else if(i1 || i2)
    if (i1 > i2)
        boid.rotationAngle += elapsedTime * obstacleAvoidancePriority;
    else
        boid.rotationAngle -= elapsedTime * obstacleAvoidancePriority;
```

This one does give me the "turn in a random direction" effect, but there are way more leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're comparing a dot-product with a `cos`. The former can have any value, the latter is limited to `[-1,+1]`. That's suspect.

Additionally, while `boid.DirectionAngle()` isn't explicitly defined, it appears to be an absolute angle (relative to coordinate system). Thus, `cos(boid.DirectionAngle())` is the component along the x-axis of the coordinate system. Yet the dot-term on the left is independent of the coordinate system. That's equally suspect.

I would have suggested scaling the dot-product, but the math seems too wrong to be fixable.

Comment: the first answer to [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/118675/need-help-with-a-field-of-view-like-collision-detector) question is where is got the idea from. It its for collision detection within a field of view but I thought It would work here as well.

Comment: @Apple_Banana: There's a `.normalized` in that code, which causes that dot-product to be restricted to the same `[-1,+1]` range.